# PHP - Autoload and Namespace issues

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader

i can't get my autoloader to find my classes if they're in a namespace.

If I say new App without the namespace Plugin\ in index.php and doesn't define a namespace in app.class.php, it works.

But when I add the namespace Plugin it says:

"Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class Plugin\App could not be loaded in.."

I've tried diffrent solutions and even went back to basics, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm running Windows 10 - 64bit and using Xammp

**index.php:**

```
/**
 * Require the autoloader
 */
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'autoloader.php';


/**
 * The init
 */
$class_ui = new Plugin\App;

$class_ui::init('Test');
```

**autoloader.php:**

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . 'classes');

spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');

spl_autoload_register();
```

**app.class.php:**

```
namespace Plugin;


class App {

  static function init($echo) {

    echo $echo;

  }

}
```

**EDIT:**

So I have an alternative solution but I don't wanna call it 'the answer' as the built-in autoload function is faster.

In my **autoloader.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {

  $parts = explode('\\', $class);

  require_once end($parts) . '.class.php';

});
```

So I passed the register fuction a custom closure that takes the classname(in my case 'Plugin/App') and just take the 'App' part and require it myself. It works as supposed too(atleast as I wanted it too).

Problems with my function at the moment:
- Not as fast as built in function.
- Apparently windows is not case-sensitive, but unix is. So on linux and so on make sure that the file name matches the classname u call. Can however make lowercase first.
- Probably other things..

If you have a better solution I'll watch it and mark it an answer if it's good.

Comment: Is `App.class.php` in a folder named `Plugin`? Also, try `App.class.php` (capitalization)

Comment: It is not in a folder called Plugin, but shouldn't be nessassry with namespaces. I did try with the App.class.php. But the default autoloader lowercase the filenames as default. Didn't work anyway.


Edit: It does work while putting in it in a folder called plugin. But this isn't really the idea of namespaces.

Comment: Why you don't use Composer for stuff like that?

Comment: I need to know the technology and methods behind this. Could/would use composer. But being able to write my own would also be nice.

Comment: Check my edit. It works as I wants it too now.

Comment: May this can be of use: there is the standard [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for PHP autoload. They also provide some examples on [github](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md).

Comment: Yea, they do the same as me in this [PSR-4 example](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md). Just way more elaborate. Thanks for your input.